# Making an executable jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable

Here is my program and it works fine but wont open once I have made it into a jar.

and the command to make it into a .jar file;

```
jar -cvfm chat.jar manifest.txt client.class
```

my program is fine, my manifest is exactly as should be soooooo.....idk please

help. every other program i make turns into a working .jar but not this one.

```
class client {

    public static Socket    s;
    public static JTextArea jta;
    public static String    server;
    public static String    name;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    s = new Socket(server, 9000);
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    String str;
                    while ((str = dis.readUTF()) != null) {
                        jta.append(str + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame j = new JFrame("Test");
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);

        jta = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
        j.add(jsp);

        JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
        jtf.setFont(new Font("", Font.BOLD, 14));
        j.add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        JTextField jtfN = new JTextField();
        jtfN.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 20));
        jp.add(jtfN);

        jp.add(new JLabel("Server:"));
        JTextField jtfS = new JTextField();
        jtfS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 20));
        jp.add(jtfS);
        int jop = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, jp, "Enter Username and Server.", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (jop == 0) {
            name = jtfN.getText();
            server = jtfS.getText();
            t.start();
        }

        jtf.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    try {
                        String data = name + ": " + jtf.getText();
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeUTF(data);
                        jta.append(data + "\n");
                        jtf.setText("");
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ///////////////////////
        j.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        j.pack();
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: I just Command prompt and Notepad++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making .jar file from .java file

1. First make sure that your file name and your class name are same. "client.java" where class is client
2. Now create a manifest.txt file. and write this

   > Main-Class: Your_Main_Class_name

   In your case it is

   > Main-Class: client

   Now save the file
3. make sure that your both file (.java and manifest.txt) on the same directory
4. Open command prompt
5. Go to that folder where you saved .java and manifest.txt file. Using command

   > cd your_path
6. Now compile your .java file using command

   > javac client.java
7. Now you have client.class file on the same folder
8. Now to make .jar file use this command

   > jar cfn client.jar manifest.txt client.class
9. Now your client.jar file is created on the same directory
10. to run .jar file use this command

    > java -jar client.jar